# Can't send notifications to an app from TestFlight

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I've...

1. Used production certificate.
2. Targeted Production server.

I've also selected push notifications in `Entitlements.pList`, which adds the following key..

```
aps-environment development
```

Firstly, why doesn't the production (non-TestFlight) version of the app require this setting in `Entitlements.pList`?

Secondly, why has it added `development` as the value? Do I need to update that every time I want a different type of build?

Even set to `production` I cannot send a notification to a device.

What do I need to do to make this feature work?

I tried using [this](http://pushtry.com/) and it says that notifications are sent ok. I click "Production" on and off with the same cert and it gives the same success messages. (If I put the wrong password in then it gives an error - nice to know something works as expected.)

What other parameters are there (I’ve got some salt and a voodoo doll) or does it simply not work?

Comment: If you want to test an production version app. You have to use production certificate and set aps-environment to production.  Please check the document and find out what you have missed. [preparing-for-notification-delivery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos#preparing-for-notification-delivery) and [creating-and-using-certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/remote-notifications-in-ios#creating-and-using-certificates)

Comment: @MSFT Oh my code was broken. Oops.